# error 3033 when appending tables

Tags: ms-access, runtime-error

My database is on my pc and it is giving runtime error 3033 when I open the application.

On start up I have configured 2 events, On Load and On Current.

On Load fetches information from one table (linked outlook table) through append and puts into another one.
On Current checks existing records for a match and loop.

My guess is that the form may be taking time to initialize while the other event is triggering up or they are clashing with each other.

The error comes and goes frequently as I keep developing my app. I want to get rid of this error.

see codes below:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Dim closingdate As Date
Dim closingemail As String
Dim Status As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim intI As Integer
Dim ticket As String
Dim subj As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("show on")

Command23.Enabled = True
subj = [subject]
closingdate = [Date]
closingemail = [email]
testemail = closingemail
testdate = closingdate
filedatecheck = [Date]
'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case, but still a good habit
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
                  'If rs![tkt] Like "*[!A-Z]" & subj & "[!A-Z]*" Then ticket = rs![tkt]: Me.Command109.Enabled = True: DoCmd.OpenForm "Closing", acNormal, WindowMode:=acDialog, WhereCondition:=ticket & Me.[tkt]: Me.[closing Date] = closingdate: Me.[Remarks (Date in one cell and Text in next cell)] = closingemail
                    If subj Like "*" & rs![tkt] & "*" Then ticket = rs![tkt]: DoCmd.OpenForm "Closing", acNormal, WindowMode:=acDialog, WhereCondition:="[tkt]=" & "'" & ticket & "'": Me.[closing Date] = closingdate: Me.[Remarks (Date in one cell and Text in next cell)] = closingemail: Me.[Status] = updatestatus
                  'Move to the next record. Don't ever forget to do this.
                  Me.Requery
         rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
   ' MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
End If
'MsgBox "Finished looping through records."

rs.Close 'Close the recordset
Set rs = Nothing 'Clean up

ErrorHandler:
   'MsgBox Err & ": " & Err.Description
End Sub
Private Sub Form_Load()
Call GetAttachments
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "cs Query Append", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.OpenQuery "cs Query Delete", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Form.Requery
End Sub
Private Sub Form_Current()
Dim closingdate As Date
Dim closingemail As String
Dim Status As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim intI As Integer
Dim ticket As String
Dim subj As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("show on")

Command23.Enabled = True
subj = [subject]
closingdate = [Date]
closingemail = [email]
testemail = closingemail
testdate = closingdate
filedatecheck = [Date]
'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case, but still a good habit
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
                  'If rs![tkt] Like "*[!A-Z]" & subj & "[!A-Z]*" Then ticket = rs![tkt]: Me.Command109.Enabled = True: DoCmd.OpenForm "Closing", acNormal, WindowMode:=acDialog, WhereCondition:=ticket & Me.[tkt]: Me.[closing Date] = closingdate: Me.[Remarks (Date in one cell and Text in next cell)] = closingemail
                    If subj Like "*" & rs![tkt] & "*" Then ticket = rs![tkt]: DoCmd.OpenForm "Closing", acNormal, WindowMode:=acDialog, WhereCondition:="[tkt]=" & "'" & ticket & "'": Me.[closing Date] = closingdate: Me.[Remarks (Date in one cell and Text in next cell)] = closingemail: Me.[Status] = updatestatus
                  'Move to the next record. Don't ever forget to do this.
                  Me.Requery
         rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
   ' MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
End If
'MsgBox "Finished looping through records."

rs.Close 'Close the recordset
Set rs = Nothing 'Clean up

ErrorHandler:
   'MsgBox Err & ": " & Err.Description
End Sub
Private Sub Form_Load()
Call GetAttachments
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
***DoCmd.OpenQuery "cs Query Append", acViewNormal, acEdit***
DoCmd.OpenQuery "cs Query Delete", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Form.Requery
End Sub
enter code here
```

and here is the sql query and the above bold line in code:
INSERT INTO master ( Priority, Subject, Requester, CC, email, [Has Attachments], [Date], Departments, [Office Phone (Exch Data)], building )
SELECT cs.Priority, cs.Subject, cs.From, cs.CC, cs.Contents, cs.[Has Attachments], cs.Received, [User Names].Department, [User Names].Phone, [User Names].Office
FROM cs, [User Names]
WHERE (((cs.From)=[User Names].[Display name]));

Comment: Events are ordered, they can't interference. show us your events code - the error resides there.

Comment: Runtime error 3033:
You do not have necessary permissions to use the " object.Have your system admin who created this object establish the appropriate permissions for you.

Comment: and what line produce such error?

Comment: DoCmd.OpenQuery "cs Query Append", acViewNormal, acEdit

Comment: see the above docmd line. If I run this query manually it works fine. but from the code it is giving this error.

Comment: Try to replace that line with CurrentDB.Execute "cs Query Append",dbfailonerror

Comment: tried that as well. same error and on the same line.